# Cron Job not starting and did everything to the point

Tags: php, cron, digital-ocean

I know this question has been asked many times before in this page but I am still stuck.

I am using a DigitalOcean droplet to run a website whose main function is to send multiple emails a day to several people. One of these emails has to be sent at a specific time on specific days so I figured I can make a cron job to do it automatically.

However, the job is not being ran. I told the script to send me an email for testing purposes and when I am running it manually I do see it. But when I want the cron to send it to me at 6 pm I am not seeing any email on my Inbox.

I have to admit cron jobs are a new thing to me, so I have no idea why it doesn't run. Can you please help me? Thanks!

Here's what I have done:

1. On Putty I run the following command:

   nano /etc/crontab
2. I added this line to the file:

   0 18    * * 1-5 root /usr/bin/php /path/to/phpfile > /path/to/debugfile
3. Saved and that's all

I stumbled upon [this question on this site](https://serverfault.com/questions/399694/cron-job-not-running) and someone mentioned to look at **var/log/cron.log** but I do not see it anywhere on this path, so now I know I did something wrong.

Comment: You spelled the path to `/var/log/cron.log` incorrectly.

Comment: @AlexD Oh, how embarassing. Thanks for pointing that out but the problem still stands :(

Comment: Do you have `cron` package installed? Also `/var/log/cron.log` is the path specific for `Debian/Ubuntu` OS, in other systems it can be different.

Comment: When running **which cron** I get **/usr/sbin/cron**, so I think I do have it. Also, when I created the droplet I selected it to be LAMP and it does take debian-based commands like **sudo apt-get update**

Comment: You'll need to check your log daemon configuration to ensure that it has logging for cron daemon enabled. Usually it is something like `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

Comment: Actually cron messages usually go into `/var/log/syslog` by default on `Debian/Ubuntu`

Comment: I saw it, great! And it seems it did attempt it. Thanks @AlexD !